# How do you use this formula for setting a GPIO pin to output (ARM assembly)?

Tags: assembly, arm, division

So basically guys, Im about to rip my hair out, I cannot grasp how to deal with this. I've been given this `( gpio_addr + (4*( GPIO_NR/10))) |= (1<<(((GPIO_NR)%10)*3)`

the gpio_address in my case is the virtual base address, which is 0x3F200000 and the first GPIO number is 17. What I dont understand is, how can you divide 17 by 10 and multiply it by 4 without loosing the remainder 7?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: That is integer division with truncation toward 0.  The remainder 7 is the bit within the MMIO register.  Also note that this is all assemble-time math, assuming GPIO_NR is a constant.

Comment: @Peter Cordes you are wrong. It does not have to be constant

Comment: @PeterJ_01: My first 2 sentences are true in general; you can do integer division / modulo at runtime with `udiv` / `mls`, or more efficiently with a multiplicative inverse like a compiler would if `GPIO_NR` isn't a build-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. Your micro has two 32 bits registers for it. Every gpio pin has its own 3 bits. First ten are in the first register, another 8 in the second. When you integer divide by ten and multiply by 4 you get the address of the register. The modulo multiple 3 gives you the position in the register. Simple math.